# Json data for handlebars.js dissappears after post

Tags: node.js, express, routes, handlebars.js

I set the page title like so for handlebars to render:

```js
// Registor
router.get('/register', function(req, res) {
    req.session.title = "Register";
    res.render('register', {
        active: {
            active_register: true
        },
        title: req.session.title
    });
});
```

I then post:

`router.post('/register', function(req, res) {`

The page title disappears along with all data sent when rendering the page.

I want the title to stay. How?

I have already tried resetting the title many ways with `res`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question there is error in handlebars. For this you have add this lines in your app.js file or main file

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views/');
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.engine('handlebars', engines.handlebars);
```

Comment: Already had this set up. // View Engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'layout',
    extname: '.hbs',
    layoutsDir: 'views/layouts',
    partialsDir: 'server/views/partials'
}));